# Optional stubbing in Mockito

Tags: java, mockito, stub

I want to create a method in superclass of test-class that stubs some commonly used methods in under-test-classes but some of those methods might not exist.

For example, I have a class hierarchy like this:

```
abstract class A {
    void search(); // implemented by subclass

    String getFoo() { return "REAL FOO"; }
}

class B extends A {
    void search() {
        getFoo();
    }   
}

class C extends A {
    void search() {
        getFoo();
        getBar();
    }   

    String getBar() { return "REAL BAR"; }
}
```

There are tons of subclasses of A (a tool generated the skeleton) thus I want to create a superclass to make it easier for me to test:

```
abstract class AbstractSearchTest {
    A underTest;

    @Test void test() {
        doReturn( "FOO" ).when( underTest ).getFoo();
        doReturn( "BAR" ).when( underTest, "getBar" ); // THE PROBLEM!

        underTest.search();
    }
}

class BSearchTest extends AbstractSearchTest {
    BSearchTest() {
        underTest = new B();
    }
}

class CSearchTest extends AbstractSearchTest {
    CSearchTest() {
        underTest = new C();
    }
}
```

Which basically says, "Before invoking `search()`, stub `getFoo()`. Oh, if the subclass happen to have `getBar()`, stub it too."
But I can't do that since it'll throw **org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.MethodNotFoundException**. How to do this?

Comment: why don't you cast it to C? I assume A B and C are all mocks. when((C)undertest.getBar).thenReturn("Bar");

Comment: I can't cast as the code is in superclass (i.e. shared by test classes of B, C, D, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use reflection to determine if the class is implemented.

```
try{
    Method m = underTest.getClass().getMethod("getBar");
    // no exception means the method is implememented
    // Do your mocking here
    doReturn( "BAR" ).when( underTest, "getBar" );
}catch(NoSuchMethodException e){}
```